# how to get value from sharedpreferences and save it arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

how to get value from shared preferences and save it array list

I want to get the string from shared preferences so that i want save that string to array list

```
SharedPreferences keyValues = context.getSharedPreferences("name_icons_list", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(keyValues.getString(""+str,"").equals("true"))

    {

        holder.tb1.setChecked(true);
        onApps.add(str);
        System.out.println("Block appp+++++"+onApps);
        System.out.println("******************************************");
        System.out.println("data retrive from database"+ position);
        System.out.println("******************************************");       

    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What's wrong with the code above? What exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: What do you want? get all the values which are stored in the "shared preferences" or anything else?

Comment: yes i wanted to get all the string from sharedpreference

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code to save preference in arraylist and vice versa

```
public String[] getApplicationList() {   Log.i("test","prefrence getapplist");
           return mApplicationList;
   }
   public void saveApplicationList(String[] applicationList) {  Log.i("test","prefrence saveapplist");
           mApplicationList = applicationList;
           String combined = "";
           for (int i=0; i<mApplicationList.length; i++){
                   combined = combined + mApplicationList[i] + ";";
           }
           mPref.edit().putString(PREF_APPLICATION_LIST, combined).commit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
String savedString = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("name_icons_list", "");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
    int numberOfToken = st.countTokens();
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfToken; i++) {
        arraylist.add(st.nextToken());
    }
```